# Is there a term for angles which are coterminal with 0?

Tags: terminology, angle

Quite simply, is there such a term, either an adjective, as in such an angle is called a [insert word here] angle or a noun as in such an angle is called a [insert word here]? Because I feel like it's a pretty glaring lexical gap if there isn't.

Comment: If you're looking for a specific name for a $360^\circ$ angle, the way we call $90^\circ$ angels "right", then I don't think there is one that is as commonly accepted. I might call it a "full circle" or something if I had to, but probably I would just say "a $360^\circ$ angle".

Comment: Except that $2\pi$ isn't the only angle that's coterminal with zero, any angle with measure $2k\pi$ for some integer $k$ is as well.